# Using one Octopress source for multiple blogs

Tags: octopress

Is it possible to use one Octopress source to handle/generate content for multiple sites? I'm just comparing it to the Wordpress multi-site feature, which you don't really need three separate WP installation just to handle 3 different blogs/sites.

But on Octopress sake, I have a slight feeling that it should be one source per blog right? I just need some confirmation on this.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box no, you could use 'pages' to achieve this but it would not be very usable IMO